Python xarray not recognizing installed cfgrib library engine
From reading around different threads related to this issue, I can confirm that I have cfgrib installed:

as well as eccodes:

However, when I try to load a file with python / jupyter, I get the error the engine is not found:
xr.open_dataset('file.grib2',engine='cfgrib')
ValueError: did not find a match in any of xarray's currently installed IO backends ['netcdf4', 'scipy', 'gini']. 
Consider explicitly selecting one of the installed engines via the ``engine`` parameter, or installing additional IO dependencies, see:

is there a specific setting that is missed on my end, or what else could be causing this issue
